# Compare two tables from MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm learning PHP for three days now. I have one table with 62 records and second table with just 2 records. I need to compare these tables and ouput same values. Comparing columns are id and t_id. I know I can use except in MySQL but I want to do it in PHP. I tried for cycle but it's comparing row by row.. So my question is how can I compare these two tables?
Thank you for any help

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please detail more your question, as written is too broad, primarly opinion based and subject to be closed soon. See here on how to ask question: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My question is how can I compare these two tables.. I tried for cycle but it's only comparing row by row :(

Comment: "Tried for cycle but it's only comparing row by row" is unclear – it *sounds* like you're saying that you've tried using a `for` loop but it didn't do what you wanted.  You should include your code in the question showing what you've tried, and explain clearly what you're trying to make it do.

Comment: Sorry but until now the only good answer to your question is: `it depends` If you want more give us more.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - it's impossible to diagnose whatever problem you're having with the information given.